# Can I deploy a Google App Engine app without manually entering an authorization code?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, continuous-integration, authorization, travis-ci

I'm using Google App Engine and Java.  When I run `mvn appengine:update`, I can deploy my application to the server.  To do so, [I must enter an authorization code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#uploading_your_app_to_production_app_engine) in the terminal window.  However, I can't do this when trying to deploy my app from Travis CI, as I can't provide terminal input.  This means if I don't resolve this, I can't use continuous integration.  **Is it possible to deploy to Google App Engine without having to manually enter an authorization code?**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide Travis CI a `service account` which will authenticate access of Travis CI to Google AppEngine.

For a minimal configuration, all you need to do is add the following to your .travis.yml:

```
deploy:
  provider: gae
  keyfile: "YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT JSON FILE"
  project: "YOUR PROJECT ID"
```

You can create a Service Account by going to the Google Cloud Console, go to “APIs & auth” -> “Credentials”, then click “Add Credential” and “Service Account”, finally clicking “JSON” to download the JSON key.

Comment: When I do that, however, I'm still prompted for an authentication code when trying to deploy from Travis.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of your config and prompt?

Comment: The relevant .travis.yml is [here](https://github.com/JesseTG/TicTacToe/blob/master/.travis.yml).  The relevant build log is [here](https://travis-ci.org/JesseTG/TicTacToe/jobs/108391840#L2504).